# Google Cloud Platform Boot Disk Pricing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, storage, google-compute-engine, cloud-storage

I'm quite confused by how GCP prices disks. We're currently using GCP's free plan, with an always free f1-micro instance. I understand that additional disks have a price per GB month, but I'm really confused on how the boot disk is priced. It comes with 10 GB by default, and since the f1-micro instance is free, I'm guessing the default 10GB is also free. However, 10GB could possibly be not enough for future usage and I'm confused on how resizing is priced. I had trouble finding any documentation on this, as there's nothing about boot disk pricing. How is space on the boot disk/default disk priced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can estimate possible spendings with [Google Cloud Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator). Also, you can see the estimated costs of your instances and Compute Engine resources when you create them in the Google Cloud Console.

To find more details have have a look at the documentation [Disks and images pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/disks-image-pricing) section [Disk pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/disks-image-pricing#disk):

> Each VM instance has at least one disk attached to it. Each disk
> incurs a cost, described in this section. In addition, if you use
> snapshots, there are separate snapshot charges.
>
> All disk-related charges in this section are prorated based on a
> granularity of seconds. This includes all persistent disk types,
> snapshot storage, and local SSD pricing.

For example:

> Persistent disks are priced by the amount of provisioned space per
> disk. Persistent disk I/O operations are included in the charges for
> provisioned space and persistent disk performance grows linearly by
> the size of the persistent disk volume, so you might want to create a
> larger or smaller persistent disk to account for your I/O needs. For
> more information, see the [persistent disk specifications](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#pdspecs).
> [image: persistent_disk]

The price will be different if you decided to use Local SSD.

In addition, have a look at the [VM instances pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing), [Networking pricing](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing), [Sustained use discounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/sustained-use-discounts) and [Committed use discounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts).

If you still have some questions you can reach [Google Cloud Sales](https://cloud.google.com/contact).

Comment: I'm confused. Is the included 10GB boot disk not free? If so, which type does it fall under?

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing#n1_standard_machine_types). As you can see `n1-standard-1` will cost you about $24.27 per month.  After that, if you check estimate when you create VM instance (without changing any settings) the estimate price will be quite the same - $24.67 per month. If you increase size of the boot disk from 10GB to 100GB the estimate price will be $28.27 per month.  If you change after that zone from `us-central1-a` to `europe-west3-a` the estimate price will be $36.07 per month and so on. Try it on your own.

Comment: By default you have standart persistent disk which could be changed to SSD persistent disk.

Comment: Does that mean that the "free" f1-micro instance is not actually free?

Comment: Have a look at this document [Always Free](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free) where you can find at the section "Compute Engine": "1 non-preemptible f1-micro VM instance per month in one of the following US regions (us-west1, us-central1, us-east1), 30 GB-months HDD" and "Your Always Free f1-micro instance limit is by time, not by instance. Each month, eligible use of all of your f1-micro instances is free until you have used a number of hours equal to the total hours in the current month. "

Comment: In addition "Google Cloud Free Tier is also available for external IP addresses that are being used by VM instances. In-use external IP addresses are available without additional cost until you have used a number of hours equal to the total hours in the current month. "